# PSD макеты сайтов, bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, psd

Вопросов много.

Макет
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpHHO.jpg

1. У меня макет размером 1600px, а экран с расширением 1440px. Как засунуть такой макет в pixel perfect, чтобы все ровно было при масштабе "1"(уменьшать до расширения экрана или обрезать отступы).
2. Как верстать на bootstrap такой макет, сетка уже встроена

Comment: у Вас ширина всего макета 1600px ? или только контента ? https://ibb.co/d1xmTd

Comment: Размер контента 1200px, а отступы по 200px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По пунктам:

1) весь контент ширина которого 1200 вставляете в обертку и центрируете.

```
<div class="screen-one"><div class="inner-wrap>контент внутри</div></div>

.screen-one { width: 100%; background: #fff;} .inner-wrap {width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

и так для каждого блока

2) контент например 1 блок делаете на всю ширину с бекграундом

3) профит

Comment: Спасибо, но как поступить с pixel perfect ?

Comment: центральный блок с контентом и будет пиксель перфект(на всех экранах по центру с размером 1200 пикс), а фон будет по бокам на весь экран

Comment: Имеется ввиду про расширение в браузере, у меня экран 1440, а макет 1600 и 160px вылазят за экран

Comment: но контент то 1200, элементы 1 экрана делаете "плавающими" (например абсолютным позиционированием) и все будет влезать

Comment: Вы похоже не понимаете о чем идет речь https://imgur.com/a/6qCUywK

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял...

Добавь в стиль эту строку (.css)

transform: scale(90%);

После этого вся вёрстка и вся страница умножится на 0.9 
1600 x 0.9 = 1440 (90%)

Это решит твою проблему. Покопай в сторону "Изменения масштаба всей страницы Css"

Comment: К сожалению не то что мне нужно